# Is short a floating point type?

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer, short

I always thought in C++ `short` was an integer type.

However, Wikipedia lists it under floating point types in this article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

I'm confused.

I'm pretty sure `short` is normally an integer, but since C++ is a huge language with lots of gotchas... Might I ask if there is a legal, even if obscure way in C++ to use `short` as floating point type?

Comment: `short` is not a floating point type and never was.

Comment: A quick check of the [C++ documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) gives you exactly the answer you seek. On that page it's listed incorrectly.

Comment: `short` is no longer on that wikipeida page. Tadman has fixed it.

Comment: That wikipedia page is a mess all-around.  The C function to calculate machine epsilon yields different values depending on the input argument (and not just differing in sign as the text suggests), but then the text asserts a particular output value without stating the input that should be passed to see it.

Comment: And.. This is yet another reason not to trust everything you see on wikipedia :)

Comment: Why did anybody vote this down? It is a properly posed question about a genuine issue created by conflicting information. Experienced programmers may think the answer is elementary, but that is not a good reason to vote down.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The reasoning being, yes there is conflicting information, but no the question isn't going to be helpful to future readers. We can't possibly respond to all the crazy stuff out there, people kinda have to exercise some autonomous fact checking, aka research.

Answer (score 6):

No `short` is not a floating point type, it is an integer type. From [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

> **Integer types**
> `int` - basic integer type. The keyword int may be omitted if any of the modifiers listed below are used. If no length modifiers are present, it's guaranteed to have a width of at least 16 bits. However, on 32/64 bit systems it is almost exclusively guaranteed to have width of at least 32 bits (see below).
>
> **Modifiers**
>
> Modifies the integer type. Can be mixed in any order. Only one of each group can be present in type name.
>
> **Signedness**
> `signed` - target type will have signed representation (this is the default if omitted)
> `unsigned` - target type will have unsigned representation
>
> **Size**
> `short` - target type will be optimized for space and will have width of at least 16 bits.
> `long` - target type will have width of at least 32 bits.
> `long long` - target type will have width of at least 64 bits.